# My code only seems to be working with some subreddits

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, reddit

It works with "memes" and some other subreddits but not with "kungenavedsbyn". I'm probably really dumb but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
    bot.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content === '-örsk') {
      let subreddits = [
        "kungenavedsbyn"

      ];
      let subreddit = subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subreddits.length))];
      let img = await api(subreddit)
      const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Här har du lite örsk`)
      .setURL(`https://www.reddit.com/r/kungenavedsbyn`)
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setImage(img)
      msg.channel.send(Embed)
    }
  });
```

Here's the message I get when I write the command in dc:

```
(node:11700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: err: [object Object]
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async functioch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/ap
(node:11700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
```

Comment: Your error indicates that something with the api call goes wrong. Wrap the callback in a `try catch` block and log the error to see better what is going wrong.

Comment: Many sub reddit are protected against bots. But not all.

Comment: @NVRM it's me and my friends subreddit and I don't believe we've added any protections against that

Comment: @Gh05d Sorry but I'm totally new to all of this but how do I do that?

Comment: Just copy this: `bot.on("message", async msg => {
  try {
    if (msg.content === "-örsk") {
      let subreddits = ["kungenavedsbyn"];
      let subreddit = subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subreddits.length)];
      let img = await api(subreddit);
      const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Här har du lite örsk`)
        .setURL(`https://www.reddit.com/r/kungenavedsbyn`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setImage(img);
      msg.channel.send(Embed);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});`

Comment: @Gh05d this is what im getting: `there has been an api error: err: [object Object]`

Comment: Sounds like you did something wrong with the reddit api or there is some bot protection (as suggested) going on.

Comment: okok thanks man i'll try a different api and hopefully it'll work

Comment: Try calling one of those bots like `!remindme` see if it works.